# How do I create a select statement that is checking other tables to see if there is data?

Tags: sql

How do I create a select statement that is checking other tables to see if there is data?

For example, suppose I have a City table that is filled with Cities and States, and then I have 3 other tables filled with businesses that have both Cities and States.  So then how do I get only cities that have data?

For example, let's take Florida.  How do I get cities in Florida that have at least 3 businesses in them?

I assume it would be something like

```
Select City C from Cities
where( Select (count) from FloridaBeds where City = C.City where (count) > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

To find a city with 1-3 beds in Florida and less than 3 beds in Kansas, try:

```
select  c.City 
from    Cities c
join    FloridaBeds fb
on      fb.City = c.City
join    KansasBeds kb
on      kb.City = c.City
group by
        c.City
having  count(distinct fb.ID) between 1 and 3
        and count(distinct kb.ID) <3
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of cities in Florida with at least 3 businesses, you could do this:

```
SELECT City
FROM Cities c
WHERE City IN
    (
    SELECT City
    FROM FloridaBeds
    GROUP BY City
    HAVING COUNT(City) >= 3
    )
```

It appears that the city name is in your FloridaBeds table.  If this is true, and you don't have a alternate key, such as CityID, you can just do this to get a list of city names.

```
SELECT City
FROM FloridaBeds
GROUP BY City
HAVING COUNT(City) >= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

To select cities that have data try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT City
FROM Cities RIGHT JOIN
FloridaBeds ON FloridaBeds.CityId = Cities.CityId
```

Comment: `right join` would return all `FloridaBeds` without a city.  I suppose you mean `inner join` ?